# is there a way to save the path of the file uploaded in html page

Tags: javascript, python, html

How should I save the path of a image uploaded in html page so that the path can be used as input to the python script

Comment: You can't; the browser obscures the source path, so all the server can see is the file name.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? What difference would it make? Every client has completely distinct file system organizations. What good does the complete source path do for you?

Comment: Actually the point is I want to input a image from the user and send the image as input to python script for processing

Answer (score 0):

Using Local Storage (require HTML 5) or cookie will solve your problem

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: why not? please explain

Comment: The OP is talking about files **uploaded** via a form: *a image uploaded in html page*.  Browsers will not reveal the full source path of such files.

Comment: He didnot mention about client side or server side right? I understand that he want to know where the picture is, then call some api provided by python

Comment: "uploaded" implies that he's talking about a client that's uploading to a server.

Comment: Also note that he mentions "in HTML page"

Comment: Yes, but he did not mention which path he need. The path may be in client or server

Comment: You do not understand the problem.

Comment: I need to give the path of the particular image to python code  so that the image gets proceesed,please help me with this

Comment: which backend language do you use?

Comment: python is the backend language